# Graphs for Comparision in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-analysis

I have a dataset like below and would like to create a graph as shown. I have tried many ways to represent data in a good way. Is there any way I could represent the following dataset as given graph.

```
d <- read.table(text="
    MONTH   ACTUAL  PREDICTED
1   January -18.0521472 -0.05621367
2   February    5.7084035   2.06652079
3   March   1.5226629   -2.13900349
4   April   -6.2783397  -1.4275986
", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
d$MONTH <- factor(d$MONTH, levels=unique(d$MONTH))
```

Graph:

[![X axis is the Month and Y axis is Values of Actual and Predicted][1]][1]

Here the X- axis is the month and Y axis is the values of Actual and Predicted. I would like to show the labels as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So there are currently votes to close this question as too broad; the original version, though, had a example figure of exactly what the OP was looking for. Not sure why it was removed, but I think it should be put back, as it used to be a perfectly clear question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  gather(var,value,-MONTH) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(MONTH,value, col=var,group = var))+
  geom_line(linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_point()
```

[image: example]